# Mongoose not saving correct schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have small project to introduce myself to some front-end technologies. I am using Node, Express, Pug, and MongoDB.

I define the user schema in my user.js file:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  username : String,
  password : String,
  jobs : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed }]

});
```

Then, in my passport.js file I start the sign up process.

```
      User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return done(err);
        }

        // check to see if theres already a user with that email
        if (user) {
          console.log('user exists');
          return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already taken.'));
        } else {
          console.log('creating new user...');
          // if there is no user with that email
          // create the user
          var newUser = new User();

          newUser.username = username;
          newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
          newUser.jobs = [{ website: 'google.com' }];

          // save the user
          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              throw err;
            }
            console.log('user saved: ', newUser);
            return done(null, newUser);
          });
        }
      });
```

The post successfully saves the new user as:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5967d2acc64d953330a3ac32"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

My goal is to have an array in the database where website links can be pushed into the array for that user.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the jobs field type as array of Mixed:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  local: { username : String, password : String },
  jobs: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed } ]
});
```

Then create the user passing all parameters to the constructor:

```
var newUser = new User({
  local: {
    username: username,
    password: User.generateHash(password),
  },
  jobs: [{ website: 'google.com' }]
});

// save the user
newUser.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('user saved: ', newUser);
  return done(null, newUser);
});
```

You could also create the user without instantiating it first:

```
// save the user
User.create({
  local: {
    username: username,
    password: User.generateHash(password),
  },
  jobs: [{ website: 'google.com' }]
}, function(err, newUser) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('user saved: ', newUser);
  return done(null, newUser);
})
```

For both these methods you will probably need to make the `generateHash` a [static method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-static).

Comment: I modified the type of the jobs array and modified the creation of the newUser. Now I get that the User.generateHash is not a function both as a instance and static function.